# Where should I add my raw SQL queries in my Laravel 4 app?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm slightly confused and need a bit of guidance if someone wouldn't mind.

Just a bit of background, my application is a website containing a simple survey (a list of questions with possible responses retrieved from the database) Thus far, I have created the models for the questions and responses tables and have defined the relationships within these classes - i.e., a question can have multiple possible responses whereas a response belongs to one question. I've used Eloquent to handle the retrieval of the data which works fine.

Now, I need to run a query using the query builder to retrieve the posted data because of some complex left joins that I cannot do using Eloquent, but I'm uncertain where to put these - do I put the query inside of a new model, or run it from my controller like I have when using Eloquent?

Comment: I'm not sure why you can't use `Eloquent` while you can use `Query Builder`, can you post you working `Query Builder` code and regarding your question, you may out it on any model or maybe in a repository.

Comment: I haven't wrote the query builder code yet as I'm uncertain of where to put it. In a nutshell, the join I need to do is on the results table that has an id for the question and an id for the response.

Comment: You can use `joins` using `Eloquent`.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I'll try using Eloquent first then. So I'd need to create a new model for the results table and then define my relationship within that model to the questions table and to the responses table? Would I be correct in saying that a result can have may questions and many responses? I'll try and post some tests.

Answer (score 2):

That code should be wrapped in a method of the model.. So if you need to do a crazy join for a user.. it would be `$user->getSomeCrazyJoinedData()`... you can also use a query scope if you want to pass arguments into it.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I may give it a try.